# How i make a good parse of a Datetime in C# for a MySQL Column?

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax-error

I have an issue when i tried to put a date into a date row in MySQL resulting in this error:

[image: this error in my program]

But my code is this:

```
DateTime tomarIngreso = dateTimePicker_FechaDeIngreso_Agregar.Value;
DateTime tomarPlazo = dateTimePicker_FechaPlazo_Agregar.Value;

string plazoFormat = tomarPlazo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string ingresoFormat = tomarIngreso.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

DateTime plazo = DateTime.ParseExact(plazoFormat, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime ingreso = DateTime.ParseExact(ingresoFormat, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The query apparently works but when i look in phpMyAdmin i get this:

[image: this...]

When i launch the program again it says the same MessageBox error and the rows with `0000-00-00` in the date can't appear in the dataGridView.

How can I resolve this?

I think is the parsing method i use for dateTimePicker i have in this format:

[image: this format]

So, when i trying to parse from `dd-MM-yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` it's kinda failing or something like that.

The columns `Ingreso` and `Plazo` have Date in the type of data. I tried with Datetime in MySQL column but it doesn't works and causes glitches in the program. I don't need Datetime to be the data type, just Date.

Comment: Try "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" in the format string

Comment: you have a datetime... and you convert it to a string..... just to parse that string into a datetime again.... _why?_

Comment: bcs i'm desperate

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `0000-00-00` is **not a valid Date**, even though it looks like one. We know this, because how would that value answer questions like "What day of the week is this?" or "What month is this?".

Therefore, you will NEVER be able to parse this input as a C# `DateOnly` or `DateTime` value. Instead, you'll need to have code somewhere (maybe in the SQL, maybe in the reporting tool, maybe in the C#) to detect it and decide how you want it to display.

Answer (score 3):

If the [`NO_ZERO_DATE` mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) is not enabled on your MySQL Server, then MySQL will allow `0000-00-00` to be stored as a "dummy" date value. I would strongly discourage you from doing this, but if that data exists in your database and you have to work with it, there are two options for handling it in C#:

1. Set `ConvertZeroDateTime=true;` in your connection string. When [this option](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#ConvertZeroDateTime) is set, MySqlConnector will convert `0000-00-00` to `DateTime.MinValue`.
2. Set `AllowZeroDateTime=true;` in your connection string. When [this option](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#AllowZeroDateTime) is set, all `DATE` values returned from `MySqlDataReader.GetValue` will be returned as [`MySqlDateTime`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqldatetimetype/) objects that support storing a `DateTime` or the special `0000-00-00` value; use `IsValidDateTime` to tell them apart.

Note that in both cases, you should use `GetValue` or `Get(MySql)DateTime` to retrieve the value from the database, instead of calling `GetString` and parsing it yourself.